# cygwin + Windows socket programming

Tags: c, windows, cygwin

I am trying to learn Socket programming in Windows and am using cygwin for the same. I found out that the required files needed for the same were at `/usr/include/w32api/`.

I took a sample program from net and tried to compile but was unable to do so.... The code for the same is

```
 #include <w32api/windows.h>
 #include <w32api/winsock.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
  int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmd, int nShow)
  {

       WORD sockVersion;
           WSADATA wsaData;
           int nret;

        sockVersion = MAKEWORD(1, 1);           // We'd like Winsock version 1.1

        // We begin by initializing Winsock

        WSAStartup(sockVersion, &wsaData);

       // rest part of code
   }
```

I compile it using gcc-3 in cygwin environment and get very strange errors .....

```
undefined reference to '_WSAStartup08' and many such errors...
```

I have taken the code from a tutorial site and thus would like to know what am i dng wrong and how should i run the program.

Thanks a lot..

edit ---------

I have also tried to use winsock2 instead of winsock.h but the errors persist...

Comment: As an aside I think it may be because of not linking  WS2_32.Lib but am not sure where to find it in cygwin .... I tried gcc socket.c -l libws2_32.a but no success.....

Comment: If you are trying to learn Windows sockets, what's the reason you chose cygwin? Windows sockets is very solid with any of the VS20xx Express DEs. Why not one of those environments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-lws2_32` should do it.

However, Cygwin has its own POSIX-compatible socket implementation on top of winsock, and mixing things up generally is not a good idea. If you want to stick with winsock, you probably want to use gcc-3's `-mno-cygwin` option that takes the Cygwin DLL out of the equation. (You'll also need to drop `w32api/` from the `#include` lines.)